# How to setup owin external login with custom table configuration

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I have configured OWIN Authentication using my existing Users table. (as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/33546674/5426308)

Now I have my own table to store facebook and google auth key for user.

I want to create token by validating user with external login in my case Google and facebook

I am not able to figure out how to do that

How do I setup external login authentication and token generation in a Web API 2 application, having an existing table for user provider

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way

http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/

git repo for this project

https://github.com/tjoudeh/AngularJSAuthentication